# Enterprise iOS app - how to track installs

Tags: ios, enterprise

We have several enterprise iOS app that our clients distribute to their users by many different ways - some clients use the Hockey app link while others simply put it up on their website for their users to download. They don't track who received the app but we need to because of our licensing agreement with one of the SDK vendors we use on the app. We pay them per device install. We have to pay the first time the app is installed and then we don't count this install again even if the user uninstalled the app and reinstalled since we already paid once. My question is how do we track which device the app was downloaded and installed on. Since Apple doesn't allow to track UDIDs not sure what other options do we have. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We have found Crashlytics to be useful for both tracking users and bugs/crashes:
https://crashlytics.com

There are also a few other 3rd party tracking services like [Google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/).

Comment: Thanks Andrew. We currently use Google Analytics to track bugs but in this case I need to know when the app was installed the very first time. For that we need to know something unique about the device so that everytime someone uninstall and reinstall, we know that it wasn't a new install.

Comment: In that case, would traking the iOS device's UUID solve that?

Comment: smartPhoneUUID = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString

Comment: Thanks again Andrew. Apple doesn't allow to track the device's UDID anymore as far as I know. They used to but not anymore.

Comment: @user881148 Does google analytics solved this problem or firebase dynamic link?